# No pulseaudio equalizer on lubuntu

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio

It's in the installed packages list, but I can't open it. It doesn't have any kind of GUI, like in Ubuntu Gnome, which I used before. Also I can't run it, because an error shows up, "no such file or directory". Thanks for any help